SCCM Failed to start Task Sequence
I need some help trying build a machine via sccm. I cant seem to task sequence.
the machine just goes on a reboot loop after diskpart. below is the smstslog.
smstslog1
I tried different machines, build stick, network point, double check bios settings. but still getting the same failed results.
whatelse could i be missing here?
